# How do I increase performance for a select query over a table of 264 million rows?

Tags: sql-server

I am using a python script which uses cursor.fetchmany(100000) to extract data from my database.The query which I am using is `select {column_name} from {table}`. I want to perform group aggregations on this data, but a group by query seems to be taking an extremely long time. Hence, i decided to perform the computations using a Python code by loading batchwise data into the memory.
The table has over 900 columns and I am performing the computations on 1 column at a time.

```
def get_data(cur,column_name):
    qry=f"select {column_name} from table"
    cur.execute(qry)
    while True:
        st=time.time()
        cur.fetchmany(100000)
        print(f"Time taken:{time.time()-st}")
```

Comment: The question as it stands is quite broad with many possible answers, starting with the most obvious one: buy faster, bigger server. Please provide some context to your problem, such as "What are you doing with the data?"

Comment: I have to agree with Alex.  General idea with this number of rows I would recommend using stored procedures and indexes on the table (you can continue then with advanced topics paritition the table etc.)

Comment: If you are on a recent version of Sql Server (2012+ I think), and this table is static (i.e. not constantly being updated) you might want to look at creating a clustered columnstore index on the table. This could dramatically speed up your grouping queries.

Comment: Consider using a columnstore index (clustered or non-clustered, as your version and needs dictate) and leaving the heavy lifting of aggregating to the server.